# Can Aberrant Mind Sorcerer replace a spell from the Psionic Spells feature at 1st level when the Sorcerer level is gained through multiclassing?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, sorcerer

Psionic Spells is a 1st level Aberrant Mind Sorcerer feature that gives a fixed list of spells known at specific levels, and on 1st level the feature gives arms of Hadar, dissonant whispers, and mind sliver. This feature also has the following rule for replacing spells from the Psionic Spells list:

> Whenever you gain a sorcerer level, you can replace one spell you gained from this feature with another spell of the same level. The new spell must be a divination or an enchantment spell from the sorcerer, warlock, or wizard spell list.

**Given you gain a level at 1st level, and given you gain this feature at 1st level, does that mean you could then replace one spell gained from the Psionic Spells list with another spell at 1st level?** (i.e. arms of Hadar for Tasha's hideous laughter)

(In my very specific case I'm multiclassing into Sorcerer; if that matters.)

Comment: I've marked your question as a dupe because I think it is entirely covered by that question. This isn't a bad thing as this question might help others find that one. If that question doesn't answer it for you, please clarify for us how and why, and we'll see what needs to be done to help you.

Comment: Oh, and Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already and see the [help] or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Comment: @Someone_Evil This is about multiclassing, which is different.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov Multiclassing is also covered by that question, albeit framed as a bonus question. We might want to fix that

Comment: @Someone_Evil Eh, yeah, I guess, though it is answered by saying "depends", when here we can give a definitive answer for this feature.

Comment: Thanks for the responses! It didn't occur to me to look for that entry so it's most appreciated. @ThomasMarkov I can edit and remove the multiclass question and ask it in a separate thread if you think it's suitable, though it looks like the "gain" entry addresses multiclassing to some degree as well.

Comment: @BeAuMaN If you’re problem is solved, we don’t need to do anything else, that’s what we’re here for.